Classify the attachment of a circle to an open cylinder
There are many ways to make a manifold with boundary by attaching a circle to an open cylinder, $x^2 + y^2 = 1 \mathop{\land} 0 < z < 1$ ("many" in the meaning that I show in an example later). My questions are those:

How are they classified, in both cases where we regard them as topological manifolds and as smooth manifolds?
Classifying attachments seems to be a common problem among many "open" manifolds, such as
simple $\mathbf{R}^2$ or more complex ones. Is there a general way to do it?

I have thought about this problem for a couple of months, but I have not been able to reach the answer by myself.
Formulation I am considering
I show a formulation for the specific case of a circle and a cylinder I am considering. However, other formulations are welcome since my formulation may lose generality or other formulations may bring more interesting results.

Let a two-dimensional topological [resp. smooth] manifold $D$ (assume manifolds are Hausdorff and second-countable) be an open cylinder, $x^2 + y^2 = 1 \mathop{\land} 0 < z < 1$. As I mentioned above, I would like to consider both the case of topological manifolds and the case of smooth manifolds. Let $E$ be a two-dimensional topological [resp. smooth] manifold with boundary such that the interior of $E$ is homeomorphic [resp. diffeomorphic] to $D$ and the boundary $\partial E$ is homeomorphic [resp. diffeomorphic] to a circle. I believe that it is unique up to homeomorphism [resp. diffeomorphic].
Define an attachment as a homeomorphism [resp. diffeomorpism] from $D$ to the interior of $E$. Let us say attachments $\varphi, \psi$ is equivalent, when $\psi \circ \varphi^{-1}$ can be extend to a homeomorphism [resp. diffeomorpism] from $E$ to $E$ itself. Then my question is how to classify the equivalence classes. The trivial difference of attachments which is come from $z \mapsto 1-z$ should be probably ignored.

Examples of attachments of a circle to an open cylinder:
Let me give two examples of the attachments. An open cylinder $D$ can be embedded into $\mathbf{R}^3$ as $r = 1 \mathop{\land} 0 < z < 1$, where $(x, y) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$. Consider one of the embeddings $\iota$. Then we can naturally attach $C\colon x^2 + y^2 = 1 \mathop{\land} z = 0$ to $\iota(D)$. It is one way of attachment.
Define a homeomorphism $\varphi\colon \iota(D) \to \iota(D)$ by $\varphi(r, \theta, z) = (r, \theta + 1/z, z)$. Then attaching $C$ to $\varphi(\iota(D))$ is another way of attachment.
These two attachments are indeed topologically different. Let us take a sequence of points in $D$ which approaches the base. Defines $\{P_i\}_{i\geq 2}$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$ by $P_i\colon (r, \theta, z) = (1, 0, 1/i)$, and $\{p_i\}$ by $p_i = \iota^{-1}(P_i)$. In the first case, $\{p_i\}$ converges to a point of $C$. However, it is not the case in the second.

(link) a Desmos graph of $\iota(D)\ \text{(green)},\ \iota(\{p_i\})\ \text{(purple)},\ \varphi \circ \iota(\{p_i\})\ \text{(red)}$
There are many examples other than the two above because we can replace $1/z$ by other functions with different growth rates when $z \searrow 0$.
Context:
I came across an interesting example of (non-Hausdorff) manifold in a Japanese book about manifolds (link). This example is from Problem 3.3.4 in the book (I apologize for my poor translation):

Let $Z$ be a topological space $\mathbf{R}^2$ without the origin. Let $a > 1$, and $A = \begin{pmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & a^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$. Define for $a$ to be equivalent to $b$ if $a = A^nb$ for some $n \in \mathbf{Z}$. Let $S$ be a quotient space of $Z$ divided by this equivalence relation.

Then $S$ consists of 4 open cylinders, each of which corresponds to the quadrants of $\mathbf{R}^2$. Either the $x$-axis and $y$-axis is divided at the origin and made into two circles. Each of these four circles attaches two cylinders whose two corresponding quadrants are adjacent to the part of the axis. For example, the circle made from $x = 0 \mathop{\land} y > 0$ attaches the cylinders made from the quadrants I and IV.
The cylinder made from quadrant I is attached to two circles made from $x = 0 \mathop{\land} y > 0$ and $y = 0 \mathop{\land} x > 0$ on the same base of the cylinder. Then I found the ways of the two attachments are different. It was where this question came to my mind.

How much topology do you know? Do you know the (topological)  classification of surfaces?

@MoisheKohan I have learnt the basic of topology, and dabbled in the algebraic topology, especially de Rham's theory. About the classification of surfaces, I know a little about the classification of two-dimensional closed manifolds, but I don't know the proofs and the strict definition of genus or suchlike.

Ok, then you should be able to write clearer than what you did. First of all, what do you mean by attaching a circle? You know that an example is not a substitute for a definition. (I can think of at least two different definitions which will result in very different answers.) Also, normally, surfaces are supposed to be Hausdorff, but you are bringing up non-Hausdorff manifolds. Do you assume that surfaces are Hausdorff?

@MoisheKohan Thank you for the reply. I implicitly assumed Hausdorff and second-countable manifolds. Regarding "attaching," I avoided strict formulation because it seems difficult in general, but I will add one formulation for this specific case I am considering to the question. If there are other formulations you had in mind, could you please share them?

The formulation I wrote is somehow different from what I intend. It may took some time to correct.

I edited. Now this formulation seems to be enough.

With this formulation, I do not think there is a reasonable classification. For instance, one can easily find continuum of equivalence classes of attachments.

@MoisheKohan Thank you for the reply. I am not very experienced with English, so my choice of the word "classify" may not be ideal. Consider a generalization of my example, where $\varphi(r, \theta, z) = (r, \theta + f(z), z)$ with $f$ a monotone $C^\infty$ function. In this case, the classification of the attachment classes seems to correspond to function classes under the equivalence relation $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$. But what if $f$ has oscillations, or if one considers more general cases? This is what I am curious about.

I do not understand your question.

Try to formulate a conjecture so that one can at least answer yes or no to your question.

@MoisheKohan Even making a conjecture is beyond my ability. Due to my lack of English proficiency, it's difficult to explain my question, but roughly speaking, I would like to know about invariants—like "genus" for the classification of closed surfaces and "de Rham cohomology" for manifolds—as much as possible, in order to understand classification more deeply. If such a question is considered inappropriate for MSE, it probably should be closed.

And if combining certain invariants leads to a complete classification, as in the case of closed surfaces, then my question would be resolved.
